# 1 Column reference, multiple tables, is it possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry, title is not so clear

Here is my table:

```
Table Example1

ID       idRef
-------------------
1         S1
2         D1
```

```
Table Example2  

ID       idPerson     Name
------------------------------
1        S1           Johnson   
2        S2           Scarlet
```

```
Table Example3
ID        idAnimal    Name
------------------------------      
1         D1          Lexa
2         D2          Jumanji
```

I would like to know if it is possible to select `idRef` having IDS from `Table Example2` and `Table Example3`

This is what I tried, but I know Its wrong

```
SELECT 
    Example2.Name AS NamePerson, Example3.Name AS NameAnimal 
FROM 
    Example1 AS Exa 
WHERE 
    Exa.idRef=Example2.idPerson 
AND 
    Exa.idRef=Example3.idAnimal
```

Comment: to make it clear what exact you want, it would help if you showed us your expected outcome from your sample data

Comment: Yeah sorry, I've forgot the output data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exists twice:

```
select idref from example1 e1
where 
  exists(
    select 1 from example2
    where idperson = e1.idref
  )
  or
  exists(
    select 1 from example3
    where idanimal = e1.idref
  )
```

This will return `idref`s existing in `example2` or `example3`.
Or with a `left join` of `example1` to the other 2 tables:

```
select e1.idref 
from example1 e1 
left join example2 e2 on e2.idperson = e1.idref
left join example3 e3 on e3.idanimal = e1.idref
where e2.idperson is not null or e3.idanimal is not null
```

Edit.
To get the `Name` column:

```
select coalesce(e2.name, e3.name) name
from example1 e1 
left join example2 e2 on e2.idperson = e1.idref
left join example3 e3 on e3.idanimal = e1.idref
where e2.idperson is not null or e3.idanimal is not null
```